# What do these npm errors mean and how do I resolve them?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, request, core-js

I'm trying to update my computer to use all of the latest packages, but when I run

`npm update -g`

I get the following errors:

```
[XX001122][DESKTOP-N4A1752] $ npm update -g
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue -> C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\gatsby -> C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\index.js
C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

> @apollo/protobufjs@1.0.3 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@apollo\protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall


> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)


> gatsby-telemetry@1.1.54 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\node_modules\gatsby-telemetry
> node src/postinstall.js || true


> gatsby-cli@2.10.7 postinstall C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli
> node scripts/postinstall.js

Success!

Welcome to the Gatsby CLI! Please visit https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/ for more information.

Usage: gatsby <command> [options]

Commands:
  gatsby develop                   Start development server. Watches files, rebuilds, and hot reloads if something changes
  gatsby build                     Build a Gatsby project.
  gatsby serve                     Serve previously built Gatsby site.
  gatsby info                      Get environment information for debugging and issue reporting
  gatsby clean                     Wipe the local gatsby environment including built assets and cache
  gatsby repl                      Get a node repl with context of Gatsby environment, see (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-repl/)
  gatsby new [rootPath] [starter]  Create new Gatsby project.
  gatsby plugin                    Useful commands relating to Gatsby plugins
  gatsby telemetry                 Enable or disable Gatsby anonymous analytics collection.

Options:
  --verbose                Turn on verbose output  [boolean] [default: false]
  --no-color, --no-colors  Turn off the color in output  [boolean] [default: false]
  --json                   Turn on the JSON logger  [boolean] [default: false]
  -h, --help               Show help  [boolean]
  -v, --version            Show the version of the Gatsby CLI and the Gatsby package in the current project  [boolean]
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.aproba.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.balanced-match.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.3 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.chownr.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.code-point-at.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.concat-map.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.console-control-strings.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.core-util-is.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.deep-extend.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.delegates.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.detect-libc.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.fs.realpath.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.has-unicode.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.4 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.inherits.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ini.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.isarray.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@0.0.8 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.1.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ms.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.npm-normalize-package-bin.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.number-is-nan.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.object-assign.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-homedir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safe-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safer-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.sax.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.semver.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.set-blocking.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.signal-exit.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-comments):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-comments' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.util-deprecate.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.wrappy.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist' -> 'C:\Users\XX001122\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.yallist.DELETE'

+ gatsby-cli@2.10.7
+ @vue/cli@3.12.1
+ npm@6.14.2
added 150 packages from 98 contributors, removed 45 packages, updated 352 packages and moved 10 packages in 80.222s
```

Sadly I haven't tried much so far because I'm afraid of screwing up my system.  I would think that uninstalling vue globally and reinstalling it would help, but I can't be sure.  What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

None of the output is much to worry about as a new developer.

```
npm WARN deprecated
```

Just means that the maintainers of the dependency have stopped working on it. In your case, it looks like one of your dependencies relies on these libraries. Unless you become a contributor of these library there is not much you can do. You can follow the rest of the line if you want extra information

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY
```

e.g.

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

You can follow the [link](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) to find out more about whats going on

It looks like gatsby has an of optional dependency on fsevents for macOS, as your on Windows this should not affect you at all.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Just means that npm cant find the file it was expecting at the given location, in this case it is due to fsevents not being installed.

Unless you are having issues running your app server or building your app the above is nothing to worry about in my experience.